# Elasticsearch kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I had elasticsearch up and running on ubuntu 14.04 VM.

Due to security reasons I wanted to install search-guard plugin (free edition).

I installed it and couldn't get it to work, so I changed the elasticsearch.yml file back to in original state (by commenting everything that weren't there before the search-guard installation) but it is still not running:

When running elasticsearch `sudo service elasticsearch start` it start but after 3 seconds its simply stop running (`sudo service elasticsearch status` shows that it isn't running + I cant access it from browser).

This is my current .yml file:

```
    # ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
    #
    # NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
    #       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
    #       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
    #
    # The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
    # the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
    #
    # Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
    # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
    #
    # ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
    #
    # Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
    #
    cluster.name: es-sg
    #
    # ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
    #
    # Use a descriptive name for the node:
    #
    node.name: master-sg-1
    #
    # Add custom attributes to the node:
    #
    #node.attr.rack: r1
    #
    # ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
    #
    # Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
    #
    #path.data: /path/to/data
    #
    # Path to log files:
    #
    #path.logs: /path/to/logs
    #
    # ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
    #
    # Lock the memory on startup:
    #
    bootstrap.memory_lock: true
    #
    # Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
    # on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
    # limit.
    #
    # Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
    #
    # ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
    #
    # Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
    #
    network.host: 11.0.7.75
    #
    # Set a custom port for HTTP:
    #
    #http.port: 9300
    #
    # For more information, consult the network module documentation.
    #
    # --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
    #
    # Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
    # The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
    #
    #discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
    #
    # Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of master-eligible nodes / 2 + 1):
    #
    #discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
    #
    # For more information, consult the zen discovery module documentation.
    #
    # ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
    #
    # Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
    #
    #gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
    #
    # For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
    #
    # ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
    #
    # Require explicit names when deleting indices:
    #
    #action.destructive_requires_name: true

    ######## Start Search Guard Demo Configuration ########
    #searchguard.ssl.transport.keystore_filepath: keystore.jks
    #searchguard.ssl.transport.truststore_filepath: truststore.jks
    #searchguard.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false
    #searchguard.ssl.http.enabled: true
    #searchguard.ssl.http.keystore_filepath: keystore.jks
    #searchguard.ssl.http.truststore_filepath: truststore.jks
    #searchguard.authcz.admin_dn:
    # - CN=kirk,OU=client,O=client,L=test, C=de

    # cluster.name: searchguard_demo
    # network.host: localhost
    ######## End Search Guard Demo Configuration ########
```

The IP that in the file is the local IP of the VM, it works with this IP at the beginning.

I hope you can help..
Thanks,
Noam

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had to simply remove search-guard manually and then elasticsearch start working again. In order to remove it simply delete /search-guard-5 folder (`sudo rm -r search-guard-5` under `/plugin` folder)